# How to fix Slick Exception of single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT

Tags: scala, slick

I tried to implement the akka-http rest example provided at
https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest
 but I'm stuck with the

```
    [ERROR] [08/28/2016 10:35:34.091] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(default)] Error during processing of request HttpRequest(HttpMethod(POST),http://127.0.0.1:9000/v1/auth/signIn,List(Host: 127.0.0.1:9000, Connection: keep-alive, Cache-Control: no-cache, Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop, User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36, Postman-Token: ec513598-b8bc-87ca-8eba-743b214fe1fa, Accept: */*, Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, Accept-Language: en-US, en;q=0.8, Timeout-Access: <function1>),HttpEntity.Strict(application/json,  {
    "login": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
  }),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
slick.SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT
    at slick.driver.JdbcStatementBuilderComponent$JdbcCompiledInsert.buildReturnColumns(JdbcStatementBuilderComponent.scala:69)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$ReturningInsertActionComposerImpl.x$12$lzycompute(JdbcActionComponent.scala:633)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$ReturningInsertActionComposerImpl.x$12(JdbcActionComponent.scala:633)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$ReturningInsertActionComposerImpl.keyColumns$lzycompute(JdbcActionComponent.scala:633)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$ReturningInsertActionComposerImpl.keyColumns(JdbcActionComponent.scala:633)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$ReturningInsertActionComposerImpl.preparedInsert(JdbcActionComponent.scala:636)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$SingleInsertAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:504)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:32)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$SimpleJdbcDriverAction.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:29)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the Scala Code:
Signup API:

```
path("signUp") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      post {
        entity(as[UserEntity]) { userEntity =>
          complete(Created -> signUp(userEntity).map(_.asJson))
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

UserEntityTable.scala

```
package oc.api.models.db

/**
  * Created by sujit on 8/27/16.
  */
import oc.api.models.UserEntity
import oc.api.utils.DatabaseService
trait UserEntityTable {
  protected val databaseService: DatabaseService
  import databaseService.driver.api._

  class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserEntity](tag, "users") {
    def id = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def username = column[String]("username")
    def password = column[String]("password")

    def * = (id, username, password) <> ((UserEntity.apply _).tupled, UserEntity.unapply)
  }

  protected val users = TableQuery[Users]
}
```

UserEntity.scala

```
package oc.api.models

/**
  * Created by sujit on 8/27/16.
  */
case class UserEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, username: String, password: String) {
  require(!username.isEmpty, "username.empty")
  require(!password.isEmpty, "password.empty")
}

case class UserEntityUpdate(username: Option[String] = None, password: Option[String] = None) {
  def merge(user: UserEntity): UserEntity = {
    UserEntity(user.id, username.getOrElse(user.username), password.getOrElse(user.password))
  }
}
```

AuthService.scala

```
package oc.api.services

import oc.api.models.{TokenEntity, UserEntity}
import oc.api.models.db.TokenEntityTable
import oc.api.utils.DatabaseService

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

/**
  * Created by sujit on 8/27/16.
  */
class AuthService(val databaseService: DatabaseService)(usersService: UsersService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends TokenEntityTable {

  import databaseService._
  import databaseService.driver.api._

  def signUp(newUser: UserEntity): Future[TokenEntity] = {
    usersService.createUser(newUser).flatMap(user => createToken(user))
  }

  def authenticate(token: String): Future[Option[UserEntity]] =
    db.run((for {
      token <- tokens.filter(_.token === token)
      user <- users.filter(_.id === token.userId)
    } yield user).result.headOption)

  def createToken(user: UserEntity): Future[TokenEntity] = db.run(tokens returning tokens += TokenEntity(userId = user.id))

}
```

Since I'm new to Scala and Slick, can anyway provide the information why this exception is occurring even though I've defined `O.AutoInc` in Model

Comment: what dbms are you using? which query is returning such exception? can you paste the full stacktrace?

Comment: I'm using MySQL. Either I run Signup or SignIn I get the exception. I've updated the Question with full stacktrace. The above stacktrace is for login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your `TokenEntity` looks something like this where `id` is auto incremented and `token` is automatically created:

```
case class TokenEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, userId: Long, token: String)
```

Now you are asking your DBMS to return multiple columns (`id`, `userId` and `token`) in your insert action which is not supported. Change

```
def createToken(user: UserEntity): Future[TokenEntity] = db.run(tokens returning tokens += TokenEntity(userId = user.id))
```

to

```
def createToken(user: UserEntity): Future[TokenEntity] = db.run(
  tokens returning tokens.map(_.userId) into((token, id) => token.copy(id = Some(id)) += TokenEntity(userId = user.id))
)
```

Here you specify column `id` to be returned on insert. The following `into` method merges `token` and the generated key. See [Inserting](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#inserting) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be in

```
  def createToken(user: UserEntity): Future[TokenEntity] = db.run(tokens returning tokens += TokenEntity(userId = user.id))
```

You are trying to return a list of Tokens, and your dbms only allows to return one: `slick.SlickException: This DBMS allows only a single AutoInc column to be returned from an INSERT`

would this work for you?

```
  def createToken(user: UserEntity): Future[TokenEntity] = db.run((self returning self) += TokenEntity(userId = user.id))
```

Comment: (self returning self) is returning error stating self value not defined

Comment: Which slick version are you using?

Comment: Slick Version v3.1.1